# Metadata file 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, teamcity

I just set up a new TeamCity build machine and I am trying to build `.Net4` solutions, but I get the error:

```
Metadata file 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' could not be found
```

and the build crashes. What is wrong or missing? This file is not there on my machine either, but the builds work fine....

Comment: It must be there to get the build to succeed.  It is always there on a properly configured build machine, certainly present on your machine.  But probably in the c:\program files (x86) directory instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, its not there. All the framework files seem to be in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. Where does this other path come from?

Comment: The Visual Studio installer puts it there.

Comment: @HansPassant, so it expects to find Visual Studio installed on the build machine?